# docker-compose link with container running on host network

Tags: docker, postgresql, docker-compose, nextcloud

I have a postgres container running as `host` network_mode and a Nextcloud container running on default (bridged) network with port `8080:80`.

How can I link the containers so that Nextcloud can access postgres?  I've tried adding this to my `docker-compose.yml`, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
services:
    nextcloud:
        external_links:
         - "postgres:postgres"
```

Command I use to run postgres:

```
docker run --name postgres --net host --restart always postgres
```

When I do that, it gives me this error

> Error while trying to create admin user: Failed to connect to the database: An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Name or service not known

**Alternate Option:**  How can I define the port I want nextcloud to listen on, so I can use it on the host network?

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to run containers with `--net host`. You can just include postgres in you docker-compose without much effort:

```
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  app:
    image: nextcloud
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    links:
      - db
    volumes:
      - nextcloud:/var/www/html
    restart: always
```

A network will be created automatically, so that you can now connect to the database on `postgres`.